# NextJs and Redux state Hydration issue

Tags: typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit

Hello I am new to NextJs. I am using NextJs 13 without App directory feature as it is experimental feature. I want to integrate Redux Toolkit in my project for state management. All the content of website is on a CMS and I want to get that data in SSR using getServerSideProps.
This is how I have implemented the Redux.

**Content-slice.ts**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { iLoginPageContent } from '@/types/contentTypes';
import { getLoginPageContent } from '@/store/content/content-thunk';
import { HYDRATE } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

export interface iContentStoreState {
  loginPage: iLoginPageContent;
}

const initialState: iContentStoreState = {
  loginPage: {} as iLoginPageContent,
};

const contentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'content',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    rehydrateContent(state, action: PayloadAction<iContentStoreState>) {
        type iKey = keyof iContentStoreState;
        for (let key in action.payload) {
        state[key as iKey] = action.payload[key as iKey];
      }
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder.addCase(getLoginPageContent.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loginPage = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export const { rehydrateContent } = contentSlice.actions;

export default contentSlice.reducer;
```

**content-thunk.ts**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import contentReducer from '@/store/content/content-slice';
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    content: contentReducer,
  },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch;
export const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

pages/login/index.ts

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { RootState, store, useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '@/store';
import { GetServerSideProps, InferGetServerSidePropsType } from 'next';
import { getLoginPageContent } from '@/store/content/content-thunk';
import { rehydrateContent } from '@/store/content/content-slice';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Login = ({
  initialState,
}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { loginPage } = useAppSelector((state) => state.content);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(rehydrateContent(initialState.content));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> {loginPage.pageHeading} </h1>
      <h4> {loginPage.pageSubHeading} </h4>
      <Link href="/login" locale="ar">
        Switch Lang
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<{
  initialState: RootState;
}> = async ({ locale }) => {
  const resp = await store.dispatch(getLoginPageContent(locale));

  return {
    props: {
      initialState: store.getState(),
    },
  };
};

export default Login;
```

**Whats the issue ?**
Now things are working fine and the page gets the content and passes the server store state to the client and the clients store also gets hydrated. But I am also getting this error on the client-side.

```
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Sign in to your Account" Client: " "
```

**Whats Happening ?**
Before the client side store hydrates in the useEffect that runs after the initial render the client store state is empty. So the client-side page becomes different form the Sever-side page.

Any way how I can safely transfer the server store state to the client store and not face this issue.

**What I tried**
I tried using the next-redux-wrapper but it has really bad typescript support and I am getting TS errors.
I can also make it so that the I use the data from the page context directly but then what would be the use of Redux.

Comment: Which version of next-redux-wrapper have you tried using?

Comment: Latest stable version 8.1.0.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you're dispatching your hydration action in a useEffect, which runs after the initial render, causing  values from your store to be uninitialized at the first render on the client. I think maybe you should focus on making next-redux-wrapper work, what kind of TS errors exactly did you encounter? If it is too long to explain it might be better suited for a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But I decided to use the app directory as it makes the redux integration much easier without next-redux-wrapper. The server components and client components were confusing at first but thing turned out well.

Comment: Cool :) In case this is a public project, would you mind sharing the repo link? I'm interested because I've tried integrating redux with app directory and failed, so I'm wondering how you did it :) Thanks

Comment: The project I am working on is private, unfortunately, But I had created a basic project for practice you can check it out.
https://github.com/hamza-mubeen-07/NextJs-Boilerplate
Also this video helped a lot.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRLjoT4r-jc&t=1220s

Comment: Oh, I've actually seen that video, but be careful since it has a massive security issue described here: https://github.com/jherr/nextjs13-pokemon/issues/2. I even once wrote a discussion on Vercel about these setups with server components here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48474. but haven't had any replies though.